# Cosa significa "essere nel giro" in questo contesto?

Tags: idioms, meaning

Nel racconto *Fino a che dura il Sole* d'Italo Calvino ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Invece, basta che lei senta parlare di
>   qualche sistema stellare che funziona in tutt'altro modo, per esempio le oscillazioni di luminosità delle «R R Lyrae», e cominciano le smanie: che là magari si fa una vita più varia, *si è più nel giro*, mentre noi restiamo confinati in quest'angolo, in un punto morto dove non succede mai niente.

Si tratta d'una famiglia che di tanto in tanto deve trasferirsi da una stella a un'altra.

Non capisco molto bene il significato dell'espressione "si è più nel giro" nella frase precedente. Nel [dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/G/giro.shtml#5) ho trovato questa definizione:

> **essere nel giro (*fam*)**
>
> • Appartenere a un determinato gruppo, specialmente di potere o di malavita; avere solidi legami con una data cerchia di persone e quindi poterne sfruttare i privilegi.

Non mi sembra che quest'espressione nel brano di Calvino abbia niente a che vedere con "appartenere a un gruppo di malavita". Quello che vuol dire il personaggio femminile del racconto è che nelle "R R Lyrae" è più facile conoscere gente "interessante" dalla quale si può estrarne dei benefici?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il senso che hai citato è l'unico che riconosco.

In questo caso direi che l'autore associa gli abitanti di *R R Lyrae* a quelli di un centro cittadino nel quale *c'è molta più vita* che non in periferia, essere fuori dal giro diventa, quindi, essere fuori dalla cerchia che *fa la bella vita*.