# Sul significato di "fare la bella vita"

Tags: idioms, meaning

Dopo aver letto questo [post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/6201)
mi sono posta la domanda sul significato dell'espressione "fare la bella vita". Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vita/) ho trovato

> *fare la bella v.* (anche, ma meno com., in forma graficamente unita *la bellavita*), vivere spensieratamente, da scioperato

Mi sa però che ci sono altre sfumature del significato non spiegate dal Treccani o forse sono io che non colgo bene tutte queste sfumature.  Potreste spiegarmele?

Comment: Cosa ti fa pensare che ci siano delle altre sfumature? Per me *fare la bella vita* ha un solo significato, quello che hai riportato nella domanda.

Comment: @DenisNardin:  La spiegazione del post citato nella domanda: non mi sembra che si possa estrarne dei benefici di una persona semplicemente per il fatto che questa viva spensieratamente, ma sì per il fatto che abbia molti soldi, per esempio.

Comment: Ah capisco il problema... La definizione intende *spensieratamente* come *senza alcuna preoccupazione*, in particolare economica (questo è implicato dalla parola *scioperato* che descrive una persona che per qualche motivo non ha bisogno di lavorare)

Comment: Vedo che hai colto il mio spunto a considerare altre espressioni idiomatiche che si accostassero a quella di Calvino. Bene. Tornando al punto, *la bella vita* la fa anche l'impiegato scarico di lavoro (magari per favori da parte del capufficio), non lo legherei strettamente al senso economico. Per me, poi, sarà che sono napoletano: *Basta ca ce sta 'o sole,
ca c'è rimasto 'o mare,
na nénna a core a core,
na canzone pe' cantá... *, finché c'è il sole, e guardo il mare abbracciando una donna e cantando, faccio la bella vita.

Answer (score 3):

È un'espressione molto comune, forse molto italiana, e il significato 
  è simile nei vari dizionari. Generalmente viene usata con una connotazione 'negativa' per suggerire il desiderio, la volontà di vivere senza responsabilità o doveri, ma solo dedicandosi  ai piaceri  della vita.

[Bella vita](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/bella-vita):

> - loc.s.f. - vita comoda, agiata, o anche mondana, scapestrata: *fare la bella vita, darsi alla bella vita*. (De Mauro)

[Fare la bella vita](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/V/vita.shtml)

> - Vivere spensieratamente, concedendosi svaghi e piaceri, divertendosi senza preoccuparsi di nulla. (Hoepli)

Comment: Dunque, non necessariamente si è ricco, no? Adesso mi viene in mente il romanzo *Ragazzi di vita* di Pasolini: i protagonisti vivono così, ma non hanno soldi.

Comment: I ragazzi di vita di Pasolini non fanno la 'bella vita' ma si arrangiano vivendo di espedienti spesso ai margini della legalità. Fare la bella vita richiede disponibilità economiche.

Answer (score 0):

Il significato è quello spiegato da Treccani. 
Aggiungerei che viene da fare l'accostamento al film di Fellini "La dolce vita".
Infine, mi viene anche un accostamento, alla lontana, con l'espressione "fare la vita" che si riferisce alla prostituzione.

Comment: Il celeberrimo  film si intitola  "***La dolce vita":*** https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_dolce_vita

Comment: Sì, scusa, mio errore...